# Building ZeroMQ on iOS version 5

Tags: ios, build, static, hyperlink, zeromq

I've been looking around a bunch. Anybody have a current guide how to build and use static libraries on iOS?

Most of the guides out there seem to be outdated and don't work. This is specifically for zeromq but documentation all around seems to be sparse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best guide I found to this question is here: http://paolodenti.blog.com/2012/07/24/zeromq-ios/

It involves setting up an Xcode project to turn zeromq into a cross-platform framework. That framework is then usable in a normal project.